# Angular 5 - Simple API call not working with HttpClient

Tags: angular, api, http

I am trying out the HttpClient module to make a call to a simple API from a tutorial, but I get "HttpErrorResponse: Unknown error" in the console.

Here is where I do the call:

```
this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/seeschweiler').subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }
```

Comment: Do you get an other errors logged in the console? Maybe something to do with CORS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See what the error is then debug from there.

```
this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/seeschweiler').subscribe(data => {
          console.log(data);
        },

    error => {
        console.log('Log the error here: ', error);
    });

      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Works fine for me, see [stackblitz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vbbfhl).

**typescript component**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div *ngIf="githubData">Id = {{githubData.id}}</div>`,
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit  {
  githubData: any;

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

    ngOnInit(){
     this.http.get('https://api.github.com/users/seeschweiler').subscribe(data => {
        this.githubData = data;
      });
    }
}
```

Comment: That StackBlitz link isn't working by the way

Comment: Just change stackoverflow to stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vbbfhl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: @user184994 - A copy/paste error I think with the link, it has been fixed.

Comment: @monogate - thanks, it was a copy paste error I think, the link should now be working.

Comment: I keep getting "Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error"

Comment: @darthprogrammer - I don't see how. Do you get this error when you click on the [stackblitz.com](https://angular-vbbfhl.stackblitz.io) link I posted?

Comment: Nope. Your example works for me.

Comment: @darthprogrammer - and the loc posted in your question is the exact place where this error message occurs? Can you please post an [mcve]? If possible try to replicate using [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Following code is working for me:-
1) At component.ts

```
GetData() {
    this.myService.GetUsers(this.someId).subscribe(
        success => {

        },
        errors => {

        }
    );
```

2) At service.ts

```
 GetUsers(someId: number) {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('someId', someId.toString());


    let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, search: params });
    return this.http.get('https://api.xyz.com/users/GetUsersList', options)
        .map(res => res.json());
}
}
```

3) Don't forget to import ".map" from rxjs/operator.